# How to query with two conditions in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am new with Neo4j and I am stucked trying to get a query with two conditions, where I want to get all the "Autors" related to "Pixar" and "Fox". So far I have tried the following two ways:

```
MATCH (a:Autor)- [:AUTOR_DE]-> (t:Título) -[:PRODUCIDO_POR] ->( p:Productora {Nombre: "Pixar"}),                                                                
and
MATCH (a:Autor)- [:AUTOR_DE]-> (t:Título) -[:PRODUCIDO_POR] ->( p:Productora {Nombre: "Fox"}),
return a,p
```

and

```
MATCH (a:Autor)- [:AUTOR_DE]-> (t:Título) -[:PRODUCIDO_POR] ->( p:Productora) 
WHERE ( (p:Productora) = "Fox" OR (p:Productora) = "Pixar")
return a,p
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that a `Productora` node stores its name in a `name` property, and that every `Productora` node has a unique `name`, this should work:

```
MATCH (a:Autor)-[:AUTOR_DE]->(:Título)-[:PRODUCIDO_POR]->(p:Productora)
WHERE p.name = "Fox" OR p.name = "Pixar"
WITH a, COLLECT(DISTINCT p) AS ps
WHERE SIZE(ps) = 2
return a, ps
```

And this should also work:

```
MATCH (fox:Productora), (pixar:Productora), (a:Autor)
WHERE fox.name = "Fox" AND pixar.name = "Pixar" AND
  (a)-[:AUTOR_DE]->(:Título)-[:PRODUCIDO_POR]->(fox) AND
  (a)-[:AUTOR_DE]->(:Título)-[:PRODUCIDO_POR]->(pixar)
return a, fox, pixar
```

Comment: Can you help with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60650902/how-to-get-all-related-nodes-idetails-based-on-node-id  ?